# Can SharedElementTransition be made interactive?

Tags: android, android-layout, shared-element-transition, sharedelementcallback

- I've used `SharedElementTransition` in my app but I want to perform the same animation with interactive touch as well.
- In iOS they have this option but I couldn't find similar solution in Android. If I write custom animation by overriding `onTouch` method then it will take a good time to be stable and perfect.
- So, I first want to be sure that if `SharedElemnetTransition` can be made interactive or not or is there any simple or more efficient solution for that? Any ideas would be highly appreciable.
  Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example video / gif about what you mean by "interactive"?

Comment: by interactive i mean to animate views on drag by figure in exactly the same pattern as SharedElementTransition performs it.

Comment: Shared elements are automatically animated when you switch activities / fragments. You can, however, animate views interactively between scenes in a fragment / activity using the new `MotionLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for shaing that. But i want to make transition between 2 different scaleTypes of ImageView. is that possible anyway?